# How should we handle errors when return it in go?

Tags: go, error-handling

Which is better?

```golang
1
err := MakeFood()
if err != nil{
    return err
}
```

```golang
2
err := MakeFood()
if err != nil{
    logs.Errorf("failed to make food, error=%v",err)
    return err
}
```

```golang
3
err := MakeFood()
if err != nil{
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to make food, error=%w",err)
}
```

```golang
4
var ErrMakeFood = errors.New("failed to make food")

err := MakeFood()
if err != nil{
    return ErrMakeFood // we discard err
}
```

In my practise, `return fmt.Errorf("xxx, error=%w",err)` is my favorite, which creates a cascaded error string when error happens and return.
But it seems that, in go builtin src code, `return err` is normal and tidy.
And sometimes we are suggested to use static error declarations(the example 4 I gave). This is the lint rule of a golang-lint named goerr113.

Comment: Define your own error package.

Comment: Do what's best for your team. If you notice that the loss of information associated with just returning the error without wrapping it, and expanding on it proves problematic, then by all means `return fmt.Errorf("xxx, error=%w", err)` is the more superior option. Sometimes, you need to break out of the norm in order to fit what's best for your needs.

Comment: The only answer is "it depends". You have to do what you determine is the best approach for the situation. Option 2 is the only one that seems objectively wrong to me; generally you should handle *or* return an error, not handle *and* return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one is better, they are all different and can be appropriate for different cases.

The 1st one,

```golang
err := MakeFood()
if err != nil{
    return err
}
```

is OK when `MakeFood` is known to provide its own context for all errors it returns (or wraps and returns — "bubbles up"); for instance, any error it ever returns is wrapped in the "failed to make food: " context.

It also fits for other cases when there's no need to provide any additional context.

The second and third are appropriate in the context of a bigger function which performs some conceptually single (atomic) task which consists from multiple steps (and making food is one of such steps); in this case it's customary to wrap errors reported by each of the steps in the same context—leading to context "chaining" when each call in the call chain adds its own context.
For instance, if our bigger function processes a food delivery order, it could look like this:

```golang
func ProcessFoodDeliveryOrder() error {
  meal, err := MakeFood()
  if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to process order: %w", err)
  }
  err := Deliver(meal, address)
  if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to process order: %w", err)
  }
  return nil
}
```

The question of whether one should use the newer Go facility of actually *nesting* errors by using the `%w` formatting verb—as opposing to merely providing textual (message) context—is an open one: not all errors need to be wrapped (and then later tested by `errors.Is` or handled by `errors.As`); there's no need to use that facility just because you know it exists and looks cool: it has its runtime cost.

The error message is better formatted using plain `: %s` combo—like with `fmt.Errorf("new context: %s", err)` because chaning the errors this way produces a trivially understandable and easily read "action: reason" text. BTW it's recommended in [The Book](https://www.gopl.io/).

The latter approach is called "a sentinel error". It's okay to use *if* the users of your package will actually *use* such error variable—directly or by testing it using `errors.Is`.
But also consider that it may be better to assert the behaviour of the errors, not comparing them to a sentinel variable. Consider reading [this](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/12/24/inspecting-errors) and look at [`net.Error`](https://golang.org/pkg/net#Error).